# Funny Haskell Behaviour: min function on three numbers, including a negative

Tags: haskell

I've been playing around with some Haskell functions in GHCi.

I'm getting some really funny behaviour and I'm wondering why it's happening.

I realized that the function `min` is only supposed to be used with two values. However, when I use three values, in my case

```
min 1 2 -5
```

I'm getting

```
-4
```

as my result.

Why is that?

Comment: Please post the code you are running.

Comment: This is due to how Haskell handles negative number literals. `-5` could mean either the number "negative 5" or the function "subtract 5". Which one is right? A choice has to be made, and in your case the choice is "subtract 5". As a rule of thumb, the "negative number" choice is made, when the number is enclosed in parentheses, like `(-5)`, or when it stands by itself, like `f x = -x`. See more [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html#X_x1)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are getting that result because this expression:

```
min 1 2 -5
```

parses as if it were parenthesized like this:

```
(min 1 2) -5
```

which is the same as this:

```
1 -5
```

which is the same as this:

```
1 - 5
```

which is of course -4.

In Haskell, function application is the most tightly-binding operation, but it is not greedy. In fact, even a seemingly simple expression like `min 1 2` actually results in two separate function calls: the function `min` is first called with a single value, 1; the return value of that function is a new, anonymous function, which will return the smaller value between 1 and its single argument. That anonymous function is then called with an argument of 2, and of course returns 1. So a more accurate fully-parenthesized version of your code is this:

```
((min 1) 2) - 5
```

But I'm not going to break everything down that far; for most purposes, the fact that what looks like a function call with multiple arguments actually turns into a series of multiple single-argument function calls is a hand-wavable implementation detail. It's important to know that if you pass too few arguments to a function, you get back a function that you can call with the rest of the arguments, but most of the time you can ignore the fact that such calls are what's happening under the covers even when you pass the right number of arguments to start with.

So to find the minimum of *three* values, you need to chain together two calls to `min` (really four calls per the logic above, but again, hand-waving that):

```
min (min 1 2) (-5)
```

The parentheses around `-5` are required to ensure that the `-` is interpreted as prefix negation instead of infix subtraction; without them, you have the same problem as your original code, only this time you would be asking Haskell to subtract a number from a function and would get a type error.

More generally, you could let Haskell do the chaining for you by applying a fold to a list, which can then contain as many numbers as you like:

```
foldl1 min [1, 2, -5]
```

(Note that in the literal list syntax, the comma and square bracket delimit the `-5`, making it clearly not a subtraction operation, so you don't need the parentheses here.)

The call [`foldl1`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Foldable.html#v%3Afoldl) *fun* *list* means "take the first two items of *list* and call *fun* on them.  Then take the result of that call and the next item of *list*, and call *fun* on those two values. Then take the result of that call and the next item of the list..."  And so on, continuing until there's no more *list*, at which point the value of the last call to *fun* is returned to the original caller.

For the specific case of `min`, there is a folded version already defined for you: [`minimum`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Foldable.html#v%3Aminimum). So you could also write the above this way:

```
minimum [1, 2, -5]
```

That behaves exactly like my `foldl1` solution; in particular, both will throw an error if handed an empty list, while if handed a single-element list, they will return that element unchanged without ever calling `min`.

Thanks to JohnL for reminding me of the existence of `minimum`.

Comment: Where can I find more info about fold?

Comment: I added an explanation. For more information, you might start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) .  Or skip straight to the Haskell specifics here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold

Comment: there's also the `minimum` function, which works on lists directly.  It's a partial function though, so it should only be used when you can guarantee the list has at least one element.

Comment: @johnL well, since my solution uses `foldl1`, it also requires a non-empty list, so that's a wash... I'll add a mention of `minimum`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

When you type `min 1 2 -5`, Haskell doesn't group it as `min 1 2 (-5)`, as you seem to think.  It instead interprets it as `(min 1 2) - 5`, that is, it does subtraction rather than negation.  The minimum of `1` and `2` is `1`, obviously, and subtracting `5` from that will (perfectly correctly) give you `-4`.

Generally, in Haskell, you should surround negative numbers with parentheses so that this kind of stuff doesn't happen unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to add to the previous answers. But you are probably looking for this function.

```
import Data.List
minimum [1, 2, -4]
```